# How to count string from last 3rd comma in Java?

Tags: java, string

I am using `String s="abc,def,hi,hello,lol"`

By using Java, how we can split the string from the last 3rd comma and get the string and string count?

Need Output as:

> ,hi,hello,lol

And the count is 13.

Can you please guide me to better code?

Below is my code, but it removes String from the last 3rd comma.

```java
String s ="abc,def,hi,hello,lol";
String[] split = s.split(",");
    
String newStr = "";
for(int i = 0 ; i < split.length -3 ; i++){ 
    newStr += split[i] + ",";
}
        
newStr = newStr.substring(0, newStr.length() - 1);
System.out.println(newStr);
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. "Can you please guide me for better code" Not if you can't provide any code. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: have a look at `String.split()` method

Comment: add what you done to achieve this!!

Comment: Your code work in the wrong sens, loop on the last cells of your `String[] split` to rebuild the corresponding string. for split.length -3 to split.length (carefull if there is not enough cells ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Look at [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class API.

You can use `lastIndexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`, `substring(int beginIndex)` and `length()` methods.

Follow below steps:

1. Call `lastIndexOf` 3 times and note down the return value.
2. Use `substring` to get string from this index.
3. Use `length` to get count.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
            String data ="abc,def,hi,hello,lol";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(data);
        sb.reverse();
        data= sb.toString();

        List<String> split = new ArrayList<String>();
        int startIndex = 0;
        int n = 0;
        for (int i = data.indexOf(',') + 1; i > 0; i = data.indexOf(',', i) + 1, n++) {
            if (n % 3 == 2) {
                split.add(data.substring(startIndex, i ));
                startIndex = i;
            }
        }
        split.add(data.substring(startIndex));
        for(String s : split)
        {
            sb = new StringBuilder(s);
            s = sb.reverse().toString();
            System.out.println(s+" : "+s.length());
        }
```

output :
,hi,hello,lol : 13
abc,def : 7

Answer (score 0):

This one arrives at the answer in only two statements:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "abc,def,hi,hello,lol";
    String[] pieces = s.split("(?=,)"); // split using positive lookahead
    String answer = (pieces.length < 3) ? "": // check if not enough pieces
        Arrays.stream(pieces).skip(pieces.length - 3).collect(Collectors.joining());
    System.out.format("Answer = \"%s\"%n", answer);
    System.out.format("Count = %d%n", answer.length());
}
```

I split at the position before each comma using positive lookahead, because if you use a simple `split(",")` then your program would fail for strings that end with comma.

Comment: @Kiran instead of saying "thank you" in a comment (although it's nice) you should upvote the answer. And instead of saying "it works" you should Accept the answer. Otherwise people will not be motivated to help you in the future. That is the way the site works for everyone's benefit.

Comment: @Partrick Parker,iam unable to upvote,i already tried long back ,but it not allowed me .It shows........." thanks for your feedback!.votes caste by those within 15 reputations are recorded,but dont not changes the publicly displayed post code "

Comment: @KiranChand ah, ok. I thought it was allowed on your own questions. Anyway, you can and should still Accept the correct answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
String output = s.substring(s.indexOf(",", 6));
System.out.println(" string from last 3rd comma -> "+ output +"\n and count -> "+ output.length() );
```

console output:

> string from last 3rd comma -> ,hi,hello,lol  and count -> 13

Comment: How do you find `6` for the indexOf ? This works for this example, not for other case